# Commerce server manager Profile definitions return 404 webpage

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-server

As I am trying to check Profile Definitions under Global resources in Commerce Server Manager and getting webpage not found 404 for all objects Address,User Object... so on.
After going through multiple threads faced the similar issue found following at
https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2016/09/sitecore-commerce-server-manager.html
Tried above approach but still it fails.

[image: Commerce Server Manager]

> Is there any other reasons that is causing "web page 404 not found"?

If it is, Please post the source that I can go through.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks&Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The blog you mentioned almost certainly has the correct solution. Make sure there is a website in IIS that is reachable via localhost and that has the widgets virtual directory, and that should solve it.

Comment: Okay, I made sure that Widgets folder is exists under Default web sites in IIS and has that is running on both application pool and sites.And also site is accessible using http://localhost:8080/. Could you please mention Do I need to check for website accessibility only for widgets folder? Thankyou.